# Find all cells changed with paste or drag

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, worksheet

SETUP:

Start with a sheet that has 3 columns.  "ID", "MyNote", "MyDate" headers.  This sheet may have thousands of rows of data.

I need to "flag" any row where the user has made a change to anything on the row.  In other code the flagged rows will be in turn be used to update a table on my SQL server.

Typically there will only be a few rows the user would change/update in a session.  So I don't want to process every row in the sheet, particularly the ones with no changes.

WHAT I HAVE WORKING NOW:

I have done this successfully by writing a "x" to an additional "flag" column any time the user makes a change.  Then later I can process any rows that were flagged with a "x" .  I did this using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
...
' Flag any lines with a change
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(TestForChangeColRange)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          ' Set the "Pending Write" Flag
          Target.Worksheet.Range(PendingWriteCol & Target.Row).Value = "x"
        Application.EnableEvents = True

...
```

PROBLEM:

That works great for individual cells being updated one at a time.  The problem comes when a user either a) uses the drag and copy (drag the bottom right corner of a cell to replicate it where dragged), or b) with a paste from some other workbook, in either case more than one cell is changed at a time.

In those cases, the Worksheet_Change sees only the first cell and not any extra cells edited by dragging or pasting.

I tried to find other similar solutions for intercepting Copy/Paste, etc., but I can't see anyway to find that if a copy was made, which cells were affected.

NEED:

All I need to know is which row numbers were affected from a drag or a copy/paste.  If I can accurately  flag those rows as updated, I'm in business.

FOLLOW-UP

Using Tim's solution.  Having trouble melding something back into it.
Additionally I need to be able to check if a particular column was edited and if it was, clear a different column.  For example, if Col 2 is edited, clear the contents of Col 3.

I tried adding the test inside the For loop, but my colno for rw.Col is coming out off.

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    'expand the range so we can flag by row, and not cell-by-cell
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng.EntireRow, rngTbl)
    For Each rw In rng.Rows 'loop over affected rows
        Me.Cells(rw.Row, PendingWriteCol).Value = "x"

        If rw.Column = RequestTypeCol Then
          Me.Cells(rw.Row, LastColToClear).ClearContents
        End If

    Next rw
End If
```

Can you show me what I've done wrong?

Comment: You need to loop the range returned by: `Intersect(Target, Me.Range(TestForChangeColRange))` and then do the code row by row.

Comment: Scott, thank you.  That's a little over my head, can you show an example?  Or point me to where I can see that?  I tried to assign that to a variable and look at the result in the debugger.  I don't see how to extract the row numbers out of it.  I see an array I think, with the values of the dragged cells, but I do not see how to tell what rows, or how many rows happened with that drag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example (following on from Scott's comment):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const PendingWriteCol As Long = 4
    Const TestForChangeColRange = "A:C"
    
    Dim rw As Range, rng As Range, rngTbl As Range
    
    Set rngTbl = Me.Range(TestForChangeColRange)
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, rngTbl) 'any monitored cells affected?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'expand the range so we can flag by row, and not cell-by-cell
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng.EntireRow, rngTbl)
        For Each rw In rng.Rows 'loop over affected rows
            Me.Cells(rw.Row, PendingWriteCol).Value = "x"
        Next rw
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you!  I did add Application.EnableEvents = False/True around the processing loop so it didn't re-trigger the worksheet change event from the "x" being written.  Appreciate getting me over the hump, very much.

Comment: I left that out because the "x" is written outside of the monitored range: it will re-trigger the handler, but it just exits without causing an endless loop.  If you add  `EnableEvents = False` then you should also add an error handler to ensure it doesn't get left turned off in the case of a run-time error

Comment: Tim, I have a follow-up question.  I posted it in the original questions.  Need to also know if a particular column is being operated on.

Comment: You'd need to remove the second Intersect, and loop over rng cell by cell

Comment: Roger, thanks.  I had just figured out I could do a subsequent loop through the columns in the same fashion.  Not as elegant but effectively the same I suppose.